# Trouble with JsonNumber

Tags: java, json

First of all, sorry for the code. It contains dutch words

I'm having trouble with retrieving data from a JSON string.

Consider this JSON string that I want to POST to my webservice:

```
{ "username" : "johndoe", "passwoord" : "password", "voornaam":"John", "achternaam":"Doe", "klassen" : [{ "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 }, { "id" : 3 }] }
```

I have a class Leerkracht (teacher) and a class Klas (this is also called a class in english and this may cause some confusion, so I'll refer to it as a grade).
Each teacher can teach in multiple grades and each grade can have multiple teachers.
This is mapped as a many to many relation.

Now, when I want to add a teacher with my POST method, I want to be able to send the grades that he has to teach to with it. This is the `"klassen" : [{ "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 }, { "id" : 3 }]` part in the JSON string.

The grades are identified by an ID. So I want to be able to send the grades with the teacher in the same JSON string.

All goes well, except when I want to read these ID's.

I use JsonReader and JsonObject (from Java EE 7) to read my JSON strings.

This is the part where I want to read the array `klassen` and get each individual ID and store it in an instance of the class Klas.

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(entityStream);
JsonObject jsonLeerkracht = reader.readObject();
List<Klas> klassen = new ArrayList<Klas>();
Klas klas = new Klas();

JsonArray jsonArray = jsonLeerkracht.getJsonArray("klassen");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonNumber jsonId = jsonLeerkracht.getJsonNumber("id");
    if (jsonId != null) {
        int id = jsonId.intValue();
    }
    klassen.add(klas);
}
```

Everything goes well untill I want to get the `id` from the array.
When I show my `jsonArray` with a `System.out.println(jsonArray)`, I get this:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]
```

So this works good I think. It has a good JSON string stored in it.

Next, when I use `System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i))`, it shows me each individual `id`:

```
{"id":1}
{"id":2}
{"id":3}
```

So that also works like a charm.

But somehow, I can't retrieve the int stored in the `id` section of the JSON string.

`JsonNumber jsonId = jsonLeerkracht.getJsonNumber("id");` should do it, but it throws a `NullPointerException`.

I think the `JsonNumber jsonId = jsonLeerkracht.getJsonNumber("id");` is not pointed to the id in the JSON string, but after hours of research, I still haven't found how to do it.

Can any of you guys help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to get the number from the JSON array, and not jsonLeerkracht (as I can't see that object being instantiated, I presume it's the JsonReader?)

Comment: Sorry, I'll add it to the code :)
jsonLeerkracht is a JsonObject, derived from a JsonReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonLeerkracht` seems to be your `JsonObject`. It contains elements named `username`, `passwoord`, `voornaam`, `achternaam`, and `klassen`. It does not contain an element named `id`. So you can't retrieve it with

```
jsonLeerkracht.getJsonNumber("id");
```

It's your JSON array that contains JSON object which has an `id` element that is a JSON number.

**EDIT**

Retrieve it like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonNumber number = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).getJsonNumber("id");
}
```

Comment: That seems to make alot of sense. I thought the JsonReader could read anything from the JSON string.

Comment: @JordyV The `JsonReader` parses the JSON. You've retrieved a `JsonObject` from it. This `JsonObject` is the root object. It has nested objects and arrays. If it could read anything but there were multiple nested elements named `id`, which would it choose? You have to go element by element.

Comment: @JordyV What are your needs?

Comment: How to make a `JsonObject` from the `klassen` object so I can access the `id`.

I can't derive how to do this for the `klassen` element from the already used code: `JsonObject jsonLeerkracht = reader.readObject()`.

Comment: Aw, is it really that simple?

Thanks for the help :)!